# Play videos on old Computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, memory, video

I have a Pentium 4 3.6 GHz, D945GCR Intel board, no external graphics card and 1GB ram pc. Recently I got it upgraded from Win 7 to Win 10 (after years... only to see how it works!). But I can't do "heavy" or multitasking jobs any more, which is normal. But then I tried to get Win 8 and still video playback for all file types is non-responsive.

What should I do? What could be the best possible OS (can be Linux distros or anything)? Also can I upgrade RAM or graphics or any other tweaks?

Comment: What player are you using, and what codecs have you been trying?

Comment: Is a RAM upgrade out of the question for you? You have two RAM slots on your board and the [Intel website](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15117/eng/d945gccr_productguide02_english.pdf) suggests you can go to 2GB without updating the BIOS.

Comment: Try download and installing [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/downloads/) player before you upgrade any hardware, and try to play videos using MPC-HC.

Comment: What videos are you playing? 480p ? 720p?

Comment: Also if it is the Intel D945GCCR Motherboard, then you can upgrade up to 4 GB ( 2 x 2 GB). http://www.memorystock.com/memory/IntelD945GCCR.html

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight Linux distro would be a lot more efficient - There are a number of them LUBUNTU is a lightweight Linux variant which would fit your needs.

You might be able to improve performance by upgrading the memory (certainly 1 GB of RAM is very much on the low side), and getting an external graphics card - if you can find old enough ones - but its almost certainly a waste of money - a US $250 low-end notebook will run rings around a P4 system, and if you use it more then occasionally will pay for itself in power savings alone.